# Are there any PHP graphing libraries that can make beautiful graphs?

Tags: php

I would like to make beautiful looking PHP graphs like the image below.  Ive looked at some php graphing libraries online but the problem is the graphs they produce are far too plain, Im looking for beautiful looking ones like this.  Should I code from scratch or is there some library I can buy?

[image]

Comment: i like fusionChart  - not affiliated

Comment: why not javascript? :) http://webdesignledger.com/resources/13-useful-javascript-solutions-for-charts-and-graphs

Comment: http://jpgraph.net/  http://www.jqplot.com/ ...

Comment: There's plenty, and most can probably generate your definition of "beautiful" if you look at them in more than cursory detail... I'd have said your sample graph was plain, but I guess that's beauty in simplicity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds better idea to draw graph with javascript / svg. And the perfect solution for that is http://www.highcharts.com/

Comment: But I think the $360.00 they charge is too expensive.

Comment: Yeah,that depends of course about the type of project. If you can go with "website" licence, it's pretty cheap. I just bought that one developer license, i feel it was worth of money.

Comment: What if I must download the generated graph? For example: in a page I've a 'Send via mail' button, and I need to send the table with raw data and the graph. How can I send if I generated in js ?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try [Google Chart Tools](http://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/index)

The area chart comes pretty close to your example.
See:
http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#area_chart

Comment: Correct link for Google is: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/index